# Confusion with a CSS transform having multiple translate properties

Tags: css, transform

In [the following demo](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/GwBJa) (WebKit only), I do not understand why there are double translates and rotates for one transform property in CSS part.

```
transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-45deg);
```

This is really a weird example. And why does the circle move like that?

Full demo:

```js
// NOTE: The change to red signifies the start of 
// the animation


// Allows elements to be accessed in a clean way
var circle = document.getElementById('circle'), 
    button = document.getElementById('button');

    // Gets element to show current percentage
var result = document.getElementById('result'),
    // Current position of circle around its path
    // in percent in reference to the original
    totalCurrentPercent = 0,
    // Percent of circle around its path in
    // percent in reference to the latest origin
    currentPercent = 0;

// Updates the percent change from the latest origin
var showPercent = window.setInterval(function() {
  if(currentPercent < 100)
  {
    currentPercent += 1;
  }
  else {
    currentPercent = 0;
  }
  result.innerHTML = currentPercent;
}, 39); // Runs at a rate based on the animation's
        // duration (milliseconds / 100)



// Checks to see if the specified rule is within 
// any of the stylesheets found in the document;
// returns the animation object if so
function findKeyframesRule(rule) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            if (ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule) { return ss[i].cssRules[j]; }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Replaces the animation based on the percent
// when activated and other hard coded 
// specifications
function change(anim) {
  // Obtains the animation object of the specified
  // animation
  var keyframes = findKeyframesRule(anim),
      length = keyframes.cssRules.length;
  
  // Makes an array of the current percent values
  // in the animation
  var keyframeString = [];  
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i ++)
  {
    keyframeString.push(keyframes[i].keyText);
  }
  
    
  // Removes all the % values from the array so
  // the getClosest function can perform calculations
  var keys = keyframeString.map(function(str) {
    return str.replace('%', '');
  });
  
  // Updates the current position of the circle to
  // be used in the calculations
  totalCurrentPercent += currentPercent;
  if(totalCurrentPercent > 100)
  {
    totalCurrentPercent -= 100;
  }
  // Self explanatory variables if you read the
  // description of getClosest
  var closest = getClosest(keys);
  
  var position = keys.indexOf(closest), 
      firstPercent = keys[position];
  
  // Removes the current rules of the specified 
  // animation
  for(var i = 0, j = keyframeString.length; i < j; i ++)
  {
    keyframes.deleteRule(keyframeString[i]);
  }
  
  // Turns the percent when activated into the
  // corresponding degree of a circle
  var multiplier = firstPercent * 3.6;
  
  // Essentially this creates the rules to set a new 
  // origin for the path based on the approximated
  // percent of the animation when activated and
  // increases the diameter of the new circular path  
  keyframes.insertRule("0% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 0) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 0) + "deg); background-color:red; }");
  keyframes.insertRule("13% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 45) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 45) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("25% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 90) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 90) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("38% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 135) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 135) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("50% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 180) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 180) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("63% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 225) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 225) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("75% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 270) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 270) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("88% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 315) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 315) + "deg); }");
  keyframes.insertRule("100% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 360) + "deg) translate(-100px,-100px) rotate(" + (multiplier + 360) + "deg); }");
  
  // Shows the circle again
  circle.style.display = "inherit";
  // Sets the animation to the newly specified rules 
  circle.style.webkitAnimationName = anim; 
  
  // Resets the approximate animation percent counter
  window.clearInterval(showPercent);
  currentPercent = 0;
  showPercent = self.setInterval(function() {
    if(currentPercent < 100)
    {
      currentPercent += 1;
    }
    else {
      currentPercent = 0;
    }
    result.innerHTML = currentPercent;
  }, 39); 
}

// Attatches the change function to the button's
// onclick function
button.onclick = function() {
  // Removes the animation so a new one can be set
  circle.style.webkitAnimationName = "none";
  // Temporarily hides the circle
  circle.style.display = "none";
  // Initializes change function
  setTimeout(function () { 
      change("rotate"); 
  }, 0);
}

// Gets the animation's closest % value based on
// the approximated % found below
function getClosest(keyframe) {
  var curr = keyframe[0];
  var diff = Math.abs (totalCurrentPercent - curr);
  for (var val = 0, j = keyframe.length; val < j; val++) {
    var newdiff = Math.abs(totalCurrentPercent - keyframe[val]);
    if (newdiff < diff) {
      diff = newdiff;
      curr = keyframe[val];
     }
  }
  return curr;
}


// Check out http://zachsaucier.com/ for more of my projects
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(0deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(0deg);
        background-color:red;
    }  
  13% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  25% {
      -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(90deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  38% {
      -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(135deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
      -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(180deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  63% {
      -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(225deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
      -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(270deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  88% {
      -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(315deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(315deg);
  }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(360deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
#circle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background-color: teal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-name:"rotate";
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position:absolute;
    left:30%;
    top:20%; 
}
#button {
  width:130px;
  background:teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id='button'>ChangeAnimation</div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Please post the code itself rather than just a link. Links may break in the future, and the question will become useless.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want explanation of how this animation works? As for the double transform properties, I think that's a typo.

Comment: I'm glad you find my article useful! Good job looking into the demo and asking about what you don't understand - it's a great way to learn!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the value of the `transform` property is a list of `<transform-function>`. If a list of `<transform-function>` is provided, then the net effect is as if each transform function had been specified separately in the order provided. For example:

```
<div style="transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(45deg)">
</div>
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
<div style="transform: translate(100px, 100px)">
    <div style="transform: rotate(45deg)">
        <div style="transform: translate(-100px, -100px)">
            <div style="transform: rotate(45deg)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for the implementation of two translates and rotates for one transform property, it was done to get a circular animation.

Speaking briefly, the first `translate` defines a center of a circular path, the first `rotate` defines an angle for the X-axis, the second `translate` defines a radius, the second `rotate` is to make the figure spin around on it’s axis.

Please look at [the article](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/) to understand it in more details on a simple example.

Comment: I approve of this message - creator of that pen

Comment: Sorry,i still do not get it. As i know, transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-45deg) should just act like transform: translateX(150px). Here is what i am thinking: First, the element is rotated by 45deg(clockwise),then is translated along with x axis, at last it is rotated by -45deg(counter-clockwise). First clockwise, then counter-clockwise which end up with no rotating.

Comment: After a day long thinking, now i know why the circle move like that.A demo explains chained transforms here [http://dabblet.com/gist/3866686] which really helped me! Actually when we use rotate, the axis was rotated also.When i realized this, i suddenly understand how the css code works. Thank you anyway, really learn something deeply again!